# Install CentOS 8, on new Laptop with No started Windows 10, Dual

Tags: centos, windows, dual-boot, ntfs, exfat

I purchased a `Lenovo` Laptop that includes Windows 10 Pro.

I would like to install `CentOS 8`, But I don't want to start `Windows 10 Pro` installation and I don't want to lose the option of first Windows startup (installation).

I can't format from Windows because Windows 10 is not started and I still don't have access to it, nor to the disk manager.

I need to deal with `NTFS` or `EXFAT` partitions (installation and `Lenovo`'s recovery drivers) from CentOS 8 installer (*CentOS 8 does not recognize partitions of type NTFS or exFAT*).

**Is it possible?**

**What considerations I must meet, in order to allow me dual boot?**

Comment: Have you tried other, live distro (e.g. Ubuntu) to change the partion scheme / prepare partions for CentOS?

Comment: unfortunately I have not hear about Live distro with NTFS and ExFAT included

Comment: @Jan maybe son distro with Linux Kernel 5.4. I remembered have (exFat included).

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 should use kernel 5.4.

Comment: Get Access https://support.lenovo.com/mx/en/solutions/ht500222-recommended-ways-to-enter-bios-boot-menu-thinkpad-thinkcentre-thinkstation#1